# How to solve unicode encode error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing this code snippet:

```
def fileLoc(self,filename):
    md5_data_with_commented_lines = hashlib.md5()
    md5_data_without_commented_lines = hashlib.md5()
    line_of_code =0
    line_of_comments = 0
    no_of_blank_lines = 0
    flag = 0
    with open(filename, 'r') as source_file:
        for line  in source_file:
            if flag == 1:
                md5_data_with_commented_lines.update(line.encode("iso-8859-1"))
                #md5_data_with_commented_lines.update(line.encode('utf-8'))
                if line.find('-->')==-1:
                    line_of_comments = line_of_comments + 1
                else:
                    line_of_comments = line_of_comments + 1
                    flag = 0
            else:
                if len(line) == 1:
                    no_of_blank_lines =no_of_blank_lines + 1
                elif line.find('<!--')!=-1:
                    md5_data_with_commented_lines.update(line.encode("iso-8859-1"))
                    #md5_data_with_commented_lines.update(line.encode('utf-8'))

                    line_of_comments = line_of_comments + 1
                    flag = 1
                    if line.find('-->')!=-1 and line.find('-->') > line.find('<!--'):
                        flag =0
                else:
                    #md5_data_with_commented_lines.update(line.encode('utf-8'))
                    #md5_data_without_commented_lines.update(line.encode('utf-8'))
                    md5_data_with_commented_lines.update(line.encode("iso-8859-1"))
                    md5_data_without_commented_lines.update(line.encode("iso-8859-1"))
                    line_of_code = line_of_code +1
                    self.check_sum_with_commented_lines = str(md5_data_with_commented_lines.hexdigest())
                    self.check_sum_without_commented_lines = str(md5_data_without_commented_lines.hexdigest())  
                    return [line_of_comments,line_of_code]
```

**But I am getting `UnicodeEncodeError` like-**

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1334-1335: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: The code snippet u posted doesn't throw any error!

Comment: What version of `Python` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you encoding the data in single byte encoding?
Ideally it should be line.decode("iso-8859-1"). which can be then accessed as line.upper()